# Autofill form from a URL LINK

Tags: joomla, webforms, autofill

I've a website where i like to create a link to this site and autofill the webform with the  unique ID on my own website.
http://www.landelijkregisterkinderopvang.nl/pp/zoeken/RegistratienummerZoekScherm.jsf

So i've tried to
http://www.landelijkregisterkinderopvang.nl/pp/zoeken/RegistratienummerZoekScherm.jsf/submit?id=xxxxx

Is it possible to send url information and directly show the information from the site,

I've tried several combinations but it won't work.....who can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla you would just need to add some php code when building the form to get the value from the url and place it in the input box. The entire input box would look something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="field_name" value="<?php echo JRequest::getVar('id'); ?>" />
```

Just in general php, you would be looking to get the value from the $_GET variable:

```
<input type="text" name="field_name" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
```

Extra piece to note that JRequest is deprecated in Joomla 3, so you would switch to using JIput: http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply. I'm quite a newbie so- do i've to create a custom html module. Which exactly from the specified url i've to put in the custom html box thanks for your help.

Comment: This requires php, which the custom html module won't support out of the box. You would have to add an extension to Joomla to get this to work. I don't use these, but you may want to check (here)[http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules] for extensions that would allow you to past the above code in the custom html module box and have it work.